# MS Access question about opening the next record in a split form-datasheet

Tags: ms-access, record, recordset

This has been a frustrating journey to date and I intuit that the solution is obvious, but I cannot see the trees for the forest.

I have MS Access db that opens to a split form. The Datasheet is on the bottom with the top of the form containing buttons to add or export, and other things.  To add a new record, the user will click a button and open blank a bound subform "new student".

If a user clicks an entry in the datasheet side ( `action:DoCmd.OpenForm "New Student", , , "[ID]=" & Me.ID, , acDialog`) the same form will open populated with the information from the datasheet; using the ID.   Works like a champ.

The **request** is to include a button on that subform, "new student", that will advance to the next record in 'student listing'. Should be easy.  I have code that works EXCEPT when there is a gap in the ID column listing.  The ID entry is the 'Primary Key' is set to automatic numbering.  If a user deletes a record, which is allowed, there is a gap in that listing.

Yes, I have tried the create button then select the next or previous record trick, but that doesn't work at all, regardless of ID numbering gap.

How do I get past the gap in numbering or is there a better way to open the 'next record'.   The code I have so far is below.  I have tried several iterations of the same process with limited success.

```
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
    Set rs = Forms![Student Listing].Form.RecordsetClone
    'MsgBox rs.RecordCount
    rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark


    If (Me.CurrentRecord < rs.RecordCount) And (Me.CurrentRecord <> 1) Then

         DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

        ElseIf (Me.CurrentRecord < rs.RecordCount) And (Me.CurrentRecord = 1) Then
           DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, 1

        Else
ErrorHandle:
        MsgBox "At the first record, will re-start at the last record.", vbOKOnly, "First Record"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast

    End If
```

Variation on a theme:

```
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
    Set rs = Forms![Student Listing].Form.RecordsetClone

    rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark   

    'MsgBox "Open Record: " & Me.CurrentRecord, vbOKOnly
    If (Me.CurrentRecord < rs.RecordCount) And (Me.CurrentRecord <> rs.RecordCount) Then
        rs.MoveNext

         'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

        ElseIf (Me.CurrentRecord = rs.RecordCount) Then
           DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, Me.CurrentRecord
        Else
ErrorHandle:
        MsgBox "At last record, will re-start at first record.", vbOKOnly, "Last Record"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
        End If

    Set rs = Nothing
```

'The below works, but jumps to the next available 'prime key' number if it has to skip a ID number:

```
Dim val As Integer
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
val = Me.ID.Value
val = val + 1
DoCmd.OpenForm "New Student", , , "[ID]=" & val, , acDialog
ErrorHandler:

Resume Next
val = 0
```

My apologies if my entry is a little verbose, I have been working at this particular task for some time.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You say `subform` but since form is opened independently it is not really a subform.

Comment: Which form do you want to advance on - 'student listing' or 'new student'?

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.    To answer your questions/comments:

1. Yup, you are right, it's not a subform, but is called from a form, so I just went with subform.

2. New Student.

Answer (score 1):

If form is opened filtered to a single record, then there is no 'previous' nor 'next' record to move to. However, code can change filter criteria by setting form Filter property.

Options for code behind NewStudent:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "StudentListing", acNext
Me.Filter = "ID=" & Forms!StudentListing.ID
```

Or

```
With Forms!StudentListing.RecordsetClone
.FindFirst "ID=" & Me.ID
.MoveNext
Me.Filter = "ID=" & !ID
End With
```

Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I didn't think to directly touch the student_listing form etc.. Brilliant. .... I agree, I added underscores "_" instead of the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution that works for me:

```
 Dim cBox As Control   
 Set cBox = Me.ActiveControl
 If cBox <> 0 Then
 With Me.RecordsetClone
 .FindFirst "ID =" & ctrl.Column(1) ' <-- the ID column from the query results
 If Not .NoMatch Then
 Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
 End If
 End With

 End If
```

The CTRL starts out as null and is a combo box with two columns. The combo box source is a query which contains a full name and the associated ID.

Fast and clean.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: I am confused. Question does not mention a combobox. Which form is this code behind? If NewStudent is filtered to a single record as indicated in question, how can you move to another with Bookmark? It is not necessary to declare and set a control object variable.

Comment: That's the problem.  If I open the NewStudent form via the Navigation Pane, all the records are available and the drop down does work.  If I open the NewStudent form via a button or hyperlink in the datatable, then only 1 record opens. Therefore, unable to cycle to the next record or previous record.  I decided to not implement that and force the end users to open each record individually.  Unless I am wrong, there is no way to "recordset/recordsetclone' from one open record then move the next.

Comment: Correct, but my answer shows how to simulate moving to next (or previous) record when form opened to a single record.